# Showing a weekly view in the calendar

Tags: calendars

Is there a way to have a weekly view in the calendar in Windows Phone 8?

I can see a daily view and a the whole month, but a 7(or 5) days view I could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no week view in the native calendar app.

A week view will be implemented in Windows Phone 8.1 and until you recieve that update you can download third-party calendar apps from the Windows Phone Store.